# libvirt_lxc not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, libvirt, lxc

I installed libvirt on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 desktop using `apt install libvirt-bin`. I then created an LXC domain named `a`.

When I tried `virsh -c lxc:/// start a`, I saw this error message:

`virsh # start a
error: Failed to start domain a
error: internal error: guest failed to start: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/libexec/libvirt_lxc: No such file or directory`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It was an environment problem with the Ubuntu libvirt-bin installation. libvirt looks for files in `/usr/libexec`, e.g. `/usr/libexec/libvirt_lxc` when starting a domain. However, `/usr/libexec` is non-existent even after `apt install libvirt-bin`.

Here's what I did:

`mkdir /usr/libexec
ln -s /usr/lib/libvirt/* /usr/libexec`

That resolved the problem.